# React trying to "let go" of item using blur

Tags: reactjs, blur, use-ref

I am trying to "Let Go" of an item in React, but I am unsure of the correct method.

I am trying to use `useRef` to store the element .. But there seems to be no `blur` method available to it.  SO I know I am thinking about this wrong, but should you not be able to use `useRef` in order to activate things like `.click` and `.blur` ?

```
function Inbox() {
    const inboxItem = useRef(null);
    
    const toggleDrawer = (id) => () => {
        alert(id);
        inboxItem.blur; // Some sort of "let go / blur" command here
    };

    return (
        <a className="inbox-item" onClick={toggleDrawer(1)} ref={inboxItem}>
            <h4>item 1</h4>
        </a>
        <a className="inbox-item" onClick={toggleDrawer(2)} ref={inboxItem}>
            <h4>item 2</h4>
        </a>
    );
}

export default Inbox;
```

I have a "swipe to delete" happening with these items, and it is interfering with the click event, as clicking on the item "holds" it ..  I need a function to be able to `blur` all `inboxItem`s  -- Is my approach not viable?